# Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: beats_management"}

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, plugins, kibana, dashboard

I get the following logs of kibana pods in Kubernetes dashboard:

```
Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: beats_management"
Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: triggers_actions_ui"
```

so that I cannot access my kibana dashboard. When I call kibana URL `http://192.168.18.90:32343/`, shows the error `Kibana server is not ready yet` still using  the working URL of elasticsearch.im using es and kibana version 7.9. Who to suggest me the fix ??

Comment: Hi ashique, Please add more details to your question. What version of k8s are you using? How did you set up k8s cluster (pods/deployments, services)? Maybe you are following some guide/tutorial? Are all pods in running state?

Comment: I  am using Kubernetes v.1 and all the pods are in running state.

Comment: Do you have any issues with the Kubernetes itself? Any connection issues between pods/services?